# Is there a property one could check when elements are too large for their container?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have this html code and I want to find a solution so that the text doesn't overflow when the screen size is smaller. For example when I resize the screen I get this overflow of the text and one has to scroll in order to read the text which is also not styled in red anymore.

One solution I thought would be is to resize the font whenever the text overflows, but I am struggling to find a solution on how to check when does it overflow.

```html
<div class="formula__content match js-match" data-color="#ff5600" data-algorithm-type="f" style="background-color: rgb(255, 86, 0); color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">

<em class="match js-match" data-algorithm-type="f1" data-color="#f2a3ca" style="padding: 10px 0px;">

<semantics>

jfrefeofjeroieofjerfjerofjerofjofoerjrfeorfefjfrefeofjeroieofjerfjerofjerofjofoerjrfeorfefjfrefeofjeroieofjerfjerofjerofjof

</semantics>
</em>
</div>
```

here is a pic of the overflow I want to get rid of when resizing, by making the font smaller.
[image]

I would be happy to use JS or jQuery to solve this issue. Thank you for any help or suggestion.

Comment: No need to use jQuery or JS - you can add => `semantics {word-break: break-word;}` in your CSS.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping problem is I have other tags that make up these words inside the semantics tag and this one isn't working unfortunately. I will update my asnwer

Comment: Yes please update the question. thanks

Comment: I think problem needs to be solved by script. Please show some more of your code. What are the other tags inside <semantics>

Answer (score 0):

You can use `word-break: break-all;` to wrap long words

```html
<div class="formula__content match js-match" data-color="#ff5600" data-algorithm-type="f" style="background-color: rgb(255, 86, 0); color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">

<em class="match js-match" data-algorithm-type="f1" data-color="#f2a3ca" style="padding: 10px 0px;">

<semantics style="word-break: break-all; ">

jfrefeofjeroieofjerfjerofjerofjofoerjrfeorfefjfrefeofjeroieofjerfjerofjerofjofoerjrfeorfefjfrefeofjeroieofjerfjerofjerofjof

</semantics>
</em>
</div>
```

Comment: unfortunately this isn't working because I have other tags inside that semantics tags that make up these words. Maybe I should edit my initial question. Also, that is why I thought to reduce the text size would be a better option.

Comment: @ga1996 you could add a css rule that word wrap to applies to all child elements of semantics with `semantics * { word-break: break-all; }` in your css file, but you cannot override it with any other more specific rule because `semantics *` would be the most specific rule for every child element.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this snippet:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    p{
        word-break: break-all;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content= "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAaaaaaa<i>aaa</i>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<b>aaa</b>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
</body>
</html>
```

`@media` helps you design page with respect to screen of multiple densities. In the code above we have set `word-break: break-all;` for all `p` elements when the screen-width is 600px or less.

Comment: unfortunately this isn't working because I have other tags inside that semantics tags that make up these words. Maybe I should edit my initial question. Also, that is why I thought to reduce the text size would be a better option.

Comment: I think `<b>` and `<i>` tags working fine inside it

Comment: yes I see that, when I apply it in inline in semantics tags in jsfiddle it works, but when I do it in my project inline in semantics tag it doesn't work. Now, I am confused I don't know why. Is there a way to count the number of elements with jquery and apply smaller font size when number of elements is i.e. >15 ?

Comment: try again, by removing all styles first and then restoring them phase wise manner. I hope that way you can find which style code not allowing to make semantics work properly

Comment: can it  be because I have formulas shown and not text? I think I need to do this in terms of tags, for example check the width of the `div` and `em` tags and accordingly make the same width for semantics and lower the font size. Is there something like `word-break: break-all;` for tags?